# How to filter datetime with three fields day,month,year in EF Core and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, lambda, .net-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.0

My Table has three fields of Datetime can be null

```
Customer
-----------------
public int? Day { get; set; }
public int? Month { get; set; }
public int? Year { get; set; }
......
```

---

How to convert three fields to Datetime and filter birthdate of Customer Beetween two Datetime ex: `(1992-08-01,1992-08-31)`in Postgresql and EFCore 3

Comment: Ideally you'd be able to simply do `new DateTime(x.Day, x.Month, x.Year)` inside an EF Core LINQ query, but that's currently blocked (see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18797).

Comment: Thanks for your awser. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `make_date()` function:

```
select make_date(year, month, day)
from the_table;
```

Or if you need that in the where clause

```
select *
from the_table
where make_date(year, month, day) between date '1992-08-01' and date '1992-08-31';
```

---

But you should really have only a single column of type `date` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Concatenation and casting function together to compare. For example like below form

```
select concat(Year,'-',Month,'-',Day)::date > concat(Year,'-',Month,'-',Day)::date
```

Real Example: It returns true or false

```
select concat('1997','-','08','-','01')::date > concat('1997','-','07','-','01')::date
```

Answer (score 0):

See this issue: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1204. Will try to work on this soon.